# How to keep my chart unchanged when deleting rows from data source?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

Could anyone kindly advise how to keep my sample chart unchanged after deleting the unnecessary Row 2?

I have a Google Sheet that contains over 50 charts whose data source is within only one big data table. Now I need to delete several useless rows which are not used for creating those charts. However, every time I delete a row, the series get changed and all my charts get changed as well. I would greatly appreciate any solutions or tips.

Link to my Sample Chart [Anyone can edit]: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jMhL2MnMvUJ82igS5RHQpUYQbIRVtjpU37n6SpEVp4o/edit?usp=sharing

**Sample Chart before Deleting Row 2**

The data range is A1:J100.

[image]

**Sample Chart after Deleting Row 2**

The data range is automatically changed to A1:J99.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Perhaps you can simply _hide_ the problematic rows instead of _deleting_ them. That should not affect your charts.

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at the sample spreadsheet. The data range of the chart is set to `A1:J100`, which obviously includes the `Customer Retention` series that has apparently been excluded manually.

The easiest solution would be to *hide* row 2 instead of *deleting* it. That way, existing charts are not affected. See the new ['Hide row 2'](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jMhL2MnMvUJ82igS5RHQpUYQbIRVtjpU37n6SpEVp4o/edit#gid=1818359134) sheet in the sample spreadsheet for an illustration.